# Where should i locate my conda env used by the root user?

Tags: python, linux, conda

I have a script that should run every night on multiple servers.

The Python environment is managed by conda and there is an environment.yml to set it up. The script sets its Python to the one in the environment that it depends on.

I want to have a conda env that can be used when running these cron jobs, without it being owned by a specific person.

Is there a way to make a "user neutral" conda env? Or do I have to create a new user that belongs to the project?